# Doubly Linked List - prev element of head not accessible

Tags: javascript, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a `reverse` function in a Doubly Linked List class. In order to do that I wanted to save the "old" head node in a variable to access it later after I switch between the head and tail. So later when I try to access the `prev` node of the variable I saved the code throws an error saying the variable value is null and `prev` cannot be accessed.
Keep in mind that beforehand I wrote the trivial functions such as push, pop, shift etc. with no errors.

```
class Node {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
    this.prev = null;
  }
}

class DoublyLinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  push(val) {
    var newNode = new Node(val);
    if (this.length === 0) {
      this.head = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = newNode;
      newNode.prev = this.tail;
      this.tail = newNode;
    }
    this.length++;
    return this;
  }

  reverse() {
    var current = this.head;
    this.head = this.tail;
    this.tail = current;
    var prev, next;
    for (let i = 0; 0 < this.length; i++) {
      prev = current.prev;
      next = current.next;
      current.next = prev;
      current.prev = next;
      current = next;
    }
    return this;
  }
}

let doubly = new DoublyLinkedList();
doubly.push("1");
doubly.push("2");
doubly.push("3");
doubly.push("4");
doubly.reverse();
```

My `reverse` function isn't tested yet because I was stuck with the problem I mentioned.
The error (thrown at the first line of the loop):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prev' of null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small typo in your code:

```
for (let i = 0; 0 < this.length; i++) {
```

should read as follows (note `i` instead of `0` in the condition):

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
```

As written, your code iterates off the end of the list setting current=null.

Comment: Thank you, had a feeling it's going to be something like this haha